# How do I copy the subject of an email in Google Inbox on Android?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Does anyone know how to copy the subject line of an email in the Inbox app, other than forwarding the email to myself and then copying the text from the body of the forward?

When I press and hold on the subject of an opened email to try to copy the text, it closes the email and returns me to the folder.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the button to reply to a message at the bottom right you’ll be able to copy the subject line as it’ll be plain text at the top of the reply.

Comment: Thanks Nano, effectively the same as what I meant when I said forwarding to self.

It's a shame, it would be nice to be able to just copy the text directly.